# How do I evaluate $\int u^m (1-u^2)^n du$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**What I've tried so far :**

$$\int u^m (1-u^2)^n du$$

$$u=\sin x \implies du= \cos x dx$$

$$\int \sin^{m}x  \cos^{n+1}x dx$$

I have no clue on how to continue from here.

*Also, if the indefinite integral isnt possible to be evaluated. I would like to know how to do a definite integral of this*

Comment: Probably better just to stick with the binomial theorem to expand out $(1-u^2)^n$.

Comment: @SimonS would there be an end to the expansion? n can be very large....

Comment: @M.S.E: $n$ may be very large indeed but always finite. We aren't taking any limits here, so $n$ is a fixed constant. Keep in mind this assumes $n$ is a positive integer (which seems plausible from the context, but it hasn't been stated).

Comment: @Clayton I've been trying, don't see how I'm able to do it, there isn't an end to my expansion. Can you please show me the expansion only? :)

Comment: In case of definite integral, if the bounds are 0 to pi/2 you can easily find the value of the above integration by applying the following formula involving the gamma function.           I = ∫(sinx)^m (cosx)^n+1 dx (with limits of integration 0 to pi/2) equals I = {gamma((m+1)/2) gamma((n+2)/2)}/{2 gamma ((m+n+3)/2)}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use the binomial theorem to expand $(1-u^2)^n$:
$$
(1-u^2)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-(u^2))^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k u^{2k}.
$$
Hence, $\int u^m (1-u^2)^n du = \int \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k (u)^{2k+m} du$. Since the summation is finite, we can interchange the integral and the summation to get
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \int (-1)^k (u)^{2k + m} du = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k (u)^{2k+m+1}}{2k+m+1}.
$$

I believe that this last series can be expressed more compactly using hypergeometric functions (a la http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5Em+%281-x%5E2%29%5En+dx), but perhaps someone more experience can clarify.

Comment: Hold on, Shouldn't it be : $$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \int (-1)^{2k}(u)^{2k + m} du = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(u)^{2k+m+1}}{2k+m+1}.
$$

Comment: You're slightly off, but I did notice an error in my answer, which I've corrected.

Comment: Got it . Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

This can be evaluated exactly as a definite integral when the domain is $(0,1)$ via the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Consider $x=u^2$ (so $dx=2u\,du$). Then,
$$ \int_0^1 u^m (1-u^2)^n\,du = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 x^{(m-1)/2} (1-x)^n\,dx = \frac{1}{2} B((m+1)/2,n+1). $$